# Showing a sequence of real numbers converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to show that for $0 < q < 1$ that the sequence ${x_n} = q^n$ converges, and to find its limit.

So I need to show that

$\forall \epsilon > 0$   there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N, |x_n - x_m | < \epsilon$ , or $|q^n - q^m| < \epsilon \\$

Once I show convergence it should be pretty easy to find its limit. Don't know where to start with this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You are trying to prove that the sequence is a Cauchy sequence. It is easier to prove directly from the definition of limit that $\lim_{n\to\infty} q^n=0$.

We have $q=\frac{1}{1+p}$ for some positive $p$. Now by the Binomial Theorem, we have $(1+p)^n \gt np$ if $n\ge 1$.  This inequality is enough for a proof based on the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of limit.

The inequality is also enough to show that the sequence $(q^n)$ is Cauchy, if you want to take that path.

**Added:** For the inequality $(1+p)^n \ge np$, we can use the Binomial Theorem
$$(1+p)^n =1+\binom{n}{1}p+\binom{n}{2}p^2+\cdots +p^n.$$
In particular, $(1+p)^n\ge np$, since $np$ is one of the terms in the above expansion.

Now suppose we are given $\epsilon\gt 0$. We have 
$$|q^n-0|=q^n =\frac{1}{(1+p)^n}\le\frac{1}{pn}.$$
To make $q^n$ less than $\epsilon$, it is enough to make $\frac{1}{np}\lt \epsilon$, that is, make $n\gt \frac{1}{p\epsilon}$. Thus if $N$ is say the smallest integer greater than $1/(p\epsilon)$, and $n\ge N$, then we will have $q^n\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: yeah, the thing is, the way the problem is set up seems it wants me to prove it converges first BEFORE exhibiting the limit. what do you think?

Comment: also, can you explain why we have $q = \frac{1}{1+p} $?

Comment: We want to find $p$ so that $q=\frac{1}{1+p}$, or equivalently so that $q(1+p)=1$, or equivalently so that $qp=1-q$. So we take $p=\frac{1-q}{q}=\frac{1}{q}-1$. This approach is one we can take *before* the logarithm has been introduced and the basic properties of exponential, logarithm proved. After we officially have log, it is more direct to say we want $q^n\lt \epsilon$, so we want $n\gt \frac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln q}$.

Comment: Or maybe you were asking why use this trick? Because it works nicely. It is easier to examine how $(1+p)^n$ behaves for large $n$ than to examine directly how $q^n$ behaves.

Comment: Thanks a lot! very helpful as usual.

Comment: You are welcome. It takes a while to get accustomed to $\epsilon$-$N$, or $\epsilon$-$\delta$. It is a question of translating the geometric intuition, which is basic, into formal language.

Comment: yeah, it is pretty difficult. I am getting there though, in another class we are also talking about open and closed sets, which uses the same sort of idea.

Comment: im looking at this again now, can you show me a full proof you would give using the binomial formula and that inequality + def of limit to show that the limit of this sequence is 0?

Answer (score 0):

You could think backwards and "guess" the limit. If $q$ is say, 0.2, what is $0.2^{1000}$? It is approximately $0$, so let us use this guess.

We want to show that there is a threshold $N$ beyond which all $n$ satisfy:
\begin{align}
|q^n-0|<\epsilon\\ q^n<\epsilon
\end{align}

So, if you have proved existence and properties of the logarithm, if you let $N=\log_q\epsilon $, for all $n>N$,

$$q^n<q^N=q^{\log_q \epsilon}=\epsilon$$

Which is exactly what we wanted.

If you haven't proved existence of the logarithm, you can use variants of the Archimedean Property to arrive at the same result.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how would I use the archimedean property?